# html disappears when I add to component.ts

Tags: angular, angular-components, contact-form, angular-forms

I'm trying to build a contact form for my angular app. I'm using this link as a guide https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/angular/forms/contact/#docsTabsOverview . HTML works fine but once I add this code to my project, the contact form disappears :

```js
import { ConnectionService } from './connection.service';
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { Component, HostListener } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss'],
})
export class AppComponent {

contactForm: FormGroup;
disabledSubmitButton: boolean = true;
optionsSelect: Array<any>;

  @HostListener('input') oninput() {

  if (this.contactForm.valid) {
    this.disabledSubmitButton = false;
    }
  }

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder, private connectionService: ConnectionService) {

  this.contactForm = fb.group({
    'contactFormName': ['', Validators.required],
    'contactFormEmail': ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.email])],
    'contactFormSubjects': ['', Validators.required],
    'contactFormMessage': ['', Validators.required],
    'contactFormCopy': [''],
    });
  }

  onSubmit() {
    this.connectionService.sendMessage(this.contactForm.value).subscribe(() => {
      alert('Your message has been sent.');
      this.contactForm.reset();
      this.disabledSubmitButton = true;
    }, error => {
      console.log('Error', error);
    });
  }

  }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you see any errors or warnings on the browser console?

Comment: Post your template as well